# In wldf for weblogic, is it possible to create a watch that triggers on appdepolyment state?

Tags: weblogic12c

Im trying to create a snmp trigger for when a appdeployment has a state other then Active, or a health state other then HEALTH_OK in wldf for weblogic ( 12.1.3), but I can't figure ut how to do this. 
Anyone know if it is possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

The ApplicationRuntimeMBean should show the state and you should be able to create an alarm from it.

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLMBR/mbeans/ApplicationRuntimeMBean.html?skipReload=true#ActiveVersionState

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, the problem was that when you look at the mbean in wlst, you can either use cmo.getHealthState(), or just cmo.healthState, both will give the same answer. When building the query for wldf, the correct way to get the metric is to use the get function, but without get, so for example  in my case:

```
NOT(${ServerRuntime//[weblogic.management.runtime.ApplicationRuntimeMBean]com.bea:Name=APPNAME,ServerRuntime=appserver1,Type=ApplicationRuntime//OverallHealthState } LIKE '%HEALTH_OK%')
```

and not overallHealthState.